# change mouse icon in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, mouse

I am using asp.net 3.5 and C#.

I want to change my mouse cursor similar to this site

http://dummyblogtrix.blogspot.com/

How can I do the same ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Don't. Just Don't.*

**Or** set the [cursor](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_cursor.asp) style on the body tag.

In order to set a 'special' non-windows icon, you have to reference a URL to a cursor icon (.cur).

```
body
{
   cursor:url(customCursor.cur);
}
```

However, I highly recommend you do not set a custom cursor. It will only serve to annoy users.

I do believe this will cause all other pointers to be overridden. I.e. your anchor tags would also use the custom icon. If you wanted to keep the standard icon, you'd have to set the cursor on all the other standard html tags, i.e.:

```
a
{
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the same pointer icon with custom color, i have few images, I convert it to .cur extension but it's not working.

Comment: What's the CSS you are using? Can you post it up?

Comment: In the body tag I am using style attribute like 
style="cursor: url(button1.cur);"

Comment: And where does the cursor file sit in the file structure? Is it in the same folder/directory as the css file?

Comment: Yes, it's in my folder directory.

Comment: ...folder directory? What does that mean? Explain your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS cursor attribute

[CSS Cursor](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csscursors.shtml)

Answer (score -1):

[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Comment: Was the link to the W3C section on the `cursor` property really voted down??